# I'm new to making discord bot with node.js and i'm stumped on this

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm new to making discord bots and I'm trying to make commands. I followed a Youtube tutorial for this, the person said to do

```js
const prefix = '-';
bot.on('message', msg=>{
    let args = msg.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
    }

witch(args[0]){
        case 'ping':
            msg.channel.send('pong');
        break;
    }
})
```

And looking at that anything with one character can work. Is there any way I can make it so it only works for `prefix` and nothing else? I've been doing a lot of digging and I can't find out how. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you please add a link to the tutorial you looked at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking but I may have an idea why that piece of code isn't working

```js
const prefix = '-';
bot.on('message', msg => {
    let args = msg.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
    if (message.content.indexOf(prefix) !== 0 || message.author.bot) return;
    //the line above means, stop working when the message doesn't start with the prefix or is sent by a bot

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'ping':
            msg.channel.send('pong');
            break;
    }
});
```

Is that what you're looking for (also there was an unneeded `}` at one point which would probably make the bot crash)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what i needed!

Comment: @TakamiyaMichael no problem, I'm glad I could help!

Comment: I'm glad you did!